# Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$, and let $N$ be the number of functions $f$ from set $A$ to set $A$ such that $f(f(x))$ is a constant function.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, permutations, graphing-functions

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$, and let $N$ be the number of functions $f$ from set $A$ to set $A$ such that $f(f(x))$ is a constant function. Find the remainder when $N$ is divided by $1000$.

**Help Needed:**

I am trying to understand this solution.

Define the three layers as domain $x$, codomain $f(x)$, and codomain $f(f(x))$. Each one of them is contained in the set $A$. We know that $f(f(x))$ is a constant function, or in other words, can only take on one value. So, we can start off by choosing that value $c$ in $7$ ways. So now, we choose the values that can be $f(x)$ for all those values should satisfy $f(f(x))=c$. Let's $S$ be that set of values. First things first, we must have $5$ to be part of $S$, for the $S$ is part of the domain of $x$. Since the values in $i\in S$ all satisfy $f(i) = 5$, we have $5$ to be a value that $f(x)$ can be. Now, for the elements other than $5$:

If we have $k$ elements other than $5$ that can be part of $S$, we will have $\binom{6}{k}$ ways to choose those values. There will also be $k$ ways for each of the elements in $A$ other than $5$ and those in set $S$ (for when function $f$ is applied on those values, we already know it would be $5$). There are $6-k$ elements in $A$ other than $5$ and those in set $S$. So, there should be $6^{6-k}$ ways to match the domain $x$ to the values of $f(x)$. So, summing up all possible values of $k$ ($[1,6]$), we have

$\sum_{k=1}^6 k^{6-k} = 6\cdot 1 + 15\cdot 16 + 20\cdot 27 + 15\cdot 16 + 6\cdot 5 + 1) = 1057$
Multiplying that by the original $7$ for the choice of $c$, we have $7 \cdot 1057 = 7\boxed{399}.$

I've given two days but still not able to  understand. I tried using smaller set.

Any other way to solve this problem are also welcomed.

This question has been asked here [Number of functions $f$ on $\{1,\cdots,7\}$ s.t. $f(f(x))$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3196934/number-of-functions-f-on-1-cdots-7-s-t-ffx-is-constant) too.

**New Update (15-05-2023)**

Let a small set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$

Let constant Value is $4,$ or $3,$ or $2,$ or $1$ i.e. $f(f(x))=4,\text{or} \;3, \text{or} \;2,\text{or}\; 1 \;\forall x\in A$ and middle layer contain only one element.

**For example**

$f(f(1))=f(4)=4, f(f(2))=f(4)=4, f(f(3))=f(4)=4, f(f(4))=f(4)=4$
$f(f(1))=f(3)=3, f(f(2))=f(3)=3, f(f(3))=f(3)=3, f(f(4))=f(3)=3$
$f(f(1))=f(2)=2, f(f(2))=f(2)=2, f(f(3))=f(2)=2, f(f(4))=f(2)=2$
$f(f(1))=f(1)=1, f(f(2))=f(1)=1, f(f(3))=f(1)=1, f(f(4))=f(1)=1$

There are **four** such function obtained above.

**Now Let Constant value of function $f(f(x)) $ is $4$ and middle layer contains two elements.**

let two elements in middle layer to be ${3,4}$

$f(f(1))=f(4)=4, f(f(2))=f(3)=4, f(f(3))=f(4)=4, f(f(4))=f(4)=4$
$f(f(1))=f(3)=4, f(f(2))=f(4)=4, f(f(3))=f(4)=4, f(f(4))=f(4)=4$
$f(f(1))=f(3)=4, f(f(2))=f(3)=4, f(f(3))=f(4)=4, f(f(4))=f(4)=4$

**Now Constant value is $4$ and middle layer contains two elements let them to be ${2,4}$**

$f(f(1))=f(2)=4, f(f(2))=f(4)=4, f(f(3))=f(4)=4, f(f(4))=f(4)=4$
$f(f(1))=f(4)=4, f(f(2))=f(4)=4, f(f(3))=f(2)=4, f(f(4))=f(4)=4$
$f(f(1))=f(2)=4, f(f(2))=f(4)=4, f(f(3))=f(2)=4, f(f(4))=f(4)=4$

**Now Constant value is $4$ and middle layer contains two elements let them to be ${1,4}$**

$f(f(1))=f(4)=4, f(f(2))=f(1)=4, f(f(3))=f(1)=4, f(f(4))=f(4)=4$
$f(f(1))=f(4)=4, f(f(2))=f(4)=4, f(f(3))=f(1)=4, f(f(4))=f(4)=4$
$f(f(1))=f(4)=4, f(f(2))=f(4)=4, f(f(3))=f(4)=4, f(f(4))=f(4)=4$

Similarly if Constant element is $1,$ or $2,$ or $(3)$

total of such function are **Thirty-Six**

Now Overall function will $40$

Comment: What do you not understand about the solution? Is there a particular sentence that trips you up? Do you understand the idea that they are going for, but not the actual execution?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, Let's Say for $k=1$ And i set $f(f(x))=1$ that means $f(1)=1$. So next i choose $1$ elements out of remaining $6$ in middle layer and say it $2$. Now it is must $f(2)=1$ and for remaining $5$ elements in upper layer can be mapped to either $1$ or $2$ so there must be $2^{5}$ mapping from top layer to bottom layer. so for $k=1$ it must be ${6 \choose 1} \cdot 2^{5}$

Comment: I suggest:  work through the solution for smaller numbers than $7$.  Try $3$ or $4$....the same logic applies

Comment: 1/ They are assuming $ c = 5$ (or maybe there's a typo in your transcription). In particular, their solution proceeds with $f(f(x)) = 5$, not $f(f(x)) = 1$, and it would be better to stick to their notation instead of having to explain when you're using which version and why.  $\quad$ 2/ Does $f(f(5)) = 5 $ imply that we must have $f(5) = 5$? Could we have $f(5) = 2$, and if so what does that imply about $f(2)$?   $\quad$ 3/ "middle layer" and "upper layer" make sense to me, but they are not defined in the solution. So you should make sure to explain exactly what you're thinking.

Comment: That isn't Christian Blatter's answer though, which is in the very link you posted OP.....so I'm not getting the problem here

Comment: @CalvinLin here is the actual Solution https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2013_AIME_II_Problems/Problem_11

Comment: @CalvinLin Lets go according to solution and say $f(f(x))=5$ that means $f(5)=5$ and now for other elements say we choose one element which will be equal to $5$ in  ${6 \choose 1}$ ways and let say $f(2)=5$ so now we can map remaining elements from top layer to middle layer in $2^{5}$ ways. Because it can be either mapped to $5$ or $2$. For example $f(3)=2$ that means $f(f(3))=f(2)=5$ and $f(3)=5$ and $f(f(3))=f(5)=5$

Comment: @CalvinLin Please Have a look at update https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639262/let-a-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-and-let-n-be-the-number-of-functions-f-fr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let $f:X\to X$ be a function such that $f(f (x))=c$ for some $c\in X$.

We can describe this situation also by stating that:$$\text{im} f\subseteq f^{-1}\left(\{c\}\right)$$

Here $c=f(x)$ for some $x$ so that $f(c)=f(f(x))=c$.

So $c$ can be recognized as a fixed point of $f$ and evidently it is unique in having this property.

We discern $3$ disjoint and covering subsets of $X$:

- $A=\{c\}$
- $B=f^{-1}\left(\{c\}\right)-\{c\}$
- $C=X-f^{-1}\left(\{c\}\right)$

If we construct such function $f$ then it must be kept in mind that elements of $C$ must be mapped to elements of $B$. This forces us to exclude the case where $C\neq\varnothing$ and $B=\varnothing$.

Next to that there are no obstacles. We can just choose the sets $A$ and $B$. Then $C$ is determined and finally for every $x\in C$ we can choose some $y\in B$ for being the element with $f(x)=y$.

Doing this construction for a set that has $n>1$ elements we find:$$n\times\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}k^{n-1-k}$$possibilities.

Here the absence of $k=0$ corresponds with leaving out "non-possibility" where $C\neq\varnothing$ and $B=\varnothing$.

---

**addendum** (concerning update of question)

Let it be that $f:\{1,2,3,4\}\to\{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $f(f(i))=4$ for every $i\in\{1,2,3,4\}$

We discern the following possibilities:

- $|f^{-1}(\{4\})|=4$ gives $1$ possibility.
- $|f^{-1}(\{4\})|=3$ gives $6$ possibilities.
- $|f^{-1}(\{4\})|=2$ gives $3$ possibilities.
- $|f^{-1}(\{4\})|=1$ gives $0$ possibilities.

The first bullet corresponds with $f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=f(4)=4$

An example for the second bullet: $f(1)=f(2)=f(4)=4$ and $f(3)=1$

An example for the third bullet: $f(1)=f(4)=4$ and $f(2)=f(3)=1$

So in total there are $6+3+1+0=10$ possibilities if the function $f\circ f$ takes value $4$ and that gives $40$ possibilities for a constant $f\circ f$.

Check yourself.

Comment: My doubt is Lets  say $f(f(x))=5$
 that means $f(5)=5$
 and now for other elements say we choose one element which will be equal to 5
 in ${6\choose 1})$
 ways and let say $f(2)=5$
 so now we can map remaining elements from top layer to middle layer in $2^5$
 ways. Because it can be either mapped to $5$
 or $2$
. For example $f(3)=2$
 that means $f(f(3))=f(2)=5$
 and $f(3)=5$
 and$ f(f(3))=f(5)=5$

Comment: If we have chosen $A=\{5\}$ and secondly $B=\{2\}$ then every element  not in $\{2,5\}$ *must* be sent to $2$ and not to $5$. Sending it to $5$ is the same as "placing it in $B$". This is not allowed anymore after deciding that $B=\{2\}$. So for such elements in the situation described in your question there are $1^5$ possibilities and not $2^5$ as you suggest.

Comment: Please Have a look at new update https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639262/let-a-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-and-let-n-be-the-number-of-functions-f-fr

Comment: I have added something to my answer that might help you finding your mistake.

Comment: @drhbb $|f^{-1}(\{4\})|$ denotes number of elements in $|f^{-1}(\{4\})|$ or value of $|f^{-1}(\{4\})|$?

Comment: @drhbb also why did we take inverse even if $f(x)$ is not invertible

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is a function and $A\subseteq Y$ then $f^{-1}(A)$ is a notation for the set $\{x\in X|f(x)\in A\}$. This is the so-called *preimage* of $A$ wrt $f$. In this context the notation does not refer to any inverse function of $f$. So here $f^{-1}(\{4\})$ denotes the set of elements of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ that are sent to $4$. Further $|f^{-1}(\{4\})|$ denotes the cardinality (i.e. number of elements) of this set.

Comment: @drhbb Thanks....

Comment: Please have look at  three images i attached. Please Let me know where I am going wrong and what am i thinking conceptually wrong about composite function

Comment: You picture $40$ functions (as it should) and I am not really eager to check them all. Why do you think that you did things wrong? Anyhow, it is enough already to focus on e.g. the $10$ functions with $f(f(i))=4$ and cumbersome to go for $40$ functions.

Comment: Sorry for trouble, If you look at first 10 function you may find out my error. And I think I am wrong because you said in your first comment and i meant in my first comment. Btw Thanks.

Comment: I've got answer to the $f:\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}\rightarrow \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ using my method. Thanks for your help

Comment: I am glad I could help you. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Combinatorially speaking, an "endofunction" or a function from S to itself is *a set of cycles of rooted trees*. This happens because an element a and its successors a, f(f), f(f(a)),... make a sequence that contains a nonperiodic part followed by a cyclic one.

In the problem above, c is not contain in a larger cycle than 1, $f(c) = c$. If the length is 2 and we have (d,c), then f(f(d)) = d. For larger cycles, f(f(c)) does not fall on c.

What we have now is a rooted tree with 7 nodes and depth maximum 2, since all elements are conected with the root c.

To simplify, we can disregard the c layer and we remain with 6 items forming a *set of pointed sets*, having the species (or class) description as

$Ens(X.Ens(X))$ with the e.g.f $exp(x.exp(x))$.

It remaind to pick up the coefficient of $ { x^6 \over 6! } = 1057$.